# Does there exist such a sequence $B$ when $p>5$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series

Let $A = (a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n)$ be the sequence of odd primes are less than or equal to a prime number $p$.

Let $C$ be the infinite ascending sequence of composite numbers that their factors are all in $A$.

Let $B$ be a sequence of $n$ consecutive numbers of $C$ such that $b_n - b_{n-1} = a_2 - a_1, \ b_{n-1} - b_{n-2}  = a_3 - a_2, \ldots, \ b_2 - b_1 = a_n - a_{n-1}$.

For example, when $p=5,\ A=3,5, \ C= 9,15,25,27,45,75,81,..., \ B=25,27$.

> Does there exist such a sequence $B$ when $p>5$?

Alternative question:

> If there exist such a sequence $B$ when $p>5$, then $b_1$ must be greater than $3p$?

*ref: see the informative comments of the same question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3486259/does-there-exist-such-a-sequence-b-when-p5).*

Comment: Have you made any progress for any $p$ other than $p=5$? Is there any $p$ for which you can prove impossibility? any $p$ for which you have found such $B$?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson I guess there's no such $B$ when $p>5$. See the informative comments of the same question on MSE,that's all: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3486259/does-there-exist-such-a-sequence-b-when-p5

Comment: When you crosspost, please mention so and include a link when you make the post (not just in response to [later questioning](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349304/does-there-exist-such-a-sequence-b-when-p5#comment875168_349304)).

Comment: @LSpice Thanks, I see that and updated the content.